# Phonegap and Firebase google Fabric / Crash Reporting

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, phonegap-plugins, phonegap, google-fabric

how do you use google fabric (eg Crash Reporting) with Phonegap, is there a phonegap plugin? Are there any phonegap-plugins? #AskFirebase

Answer (score 0):

Mike from Fabric here. Fabric does not support Phonegap built apps at this time.